# How to create a sidebar that will overlap a column of Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a sidebar that will overlap with a column in bootstrap. When I click a `button` on the screen, the sidebar will appear and when I click `x`, the bar will disappear. I am using Bootstrap row and column layout for my page. For some reason, the bar would go to the bottom of the page and the button would not respond to my click.

My HTML is:

```
<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="row>
 <div class="col-8">...</div> 
 <div class="col-4">...</div> 
 <div id="mySidenav"></div> 
</div>
<span id="pr-btn" style="position:fixed;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">&#9776; open</span>
</body>.
```

My CSS is

```
#mySidenav {
 position: abolute; 
 width: 0; 
 right: 0; 
 height: 100%; 
 background-color: #123456
}
```

My JQuery is

```
$("#pr-btn").click(() => {
  let width = $("#mySidenav").css("width");
  if(width == 0) {
    $("#mySidenav").css("width", "33.3%");
  } else {
    $("#mySidenav").css("width", "0");
  }
})
```

Comment: pleas share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: For something to overlap something else, my thoughts immediately go to the usage of the CSS `position` and `z-index` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it using:

```
$("#pr-btn").click(()=>{
  $("#originalColumn").fadeOut();
  $("#mySidenav").fadeIn();
});
```

Other solutions are also welcome.